# Access data from an object in the dictionary

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dictionary

I have a dictionary that contains a class `File` in the value:

```
public Dictionary<string, File> mydict = new Dictionary<string, File>();
```

The class object `File folder = new File()` contains different variables such as `First` and `Last` (which are parsed from an xml) :

```
folder.First = Root.Attribute("First").Value;
folder.Last = Root.Attribute("Last").Value;
```

I want to know how I can grab variables inside the `folder` object inside the `File` class in my unit tests.

How can I use this data in my unit tests to work with

```
Assert.IsNotNull, Assert.AreEqual
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem a little more clearly? Are you just looking for `mydict.Values.First().First`, for example?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior no I am looking for how I can get my variables stored inside my object `folder` to work with the Assert tests? 

If these were just regular variables, I could easily call them in my `Assert` tests using e.g. `Assert.IsNotNull(<object>.First);` but since they are inside the `mydict`dictionary, I have trouble doing the unit testing

Comment: `Assert.IsNotNull(mydict.Values.First().First);`?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior when I write `Assert.IsNotNull(mydict.Values. ...)`, it only displays `.Count` and `.CopyTo`. It doesn't display the `First` variable

Comment: Add `using System.Linq;` to be able to use First()

Comment: it is already there. @yassinMi. I feel like I am missing a piece of information to include here but can't figure out what it is

Comment: It might help to just walk through some examples of how to use a Dictionary: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-6.0#examples Once you are able to get any value out of the dictionary, you can access its properties the same way you would any other variable of that type.